# JNI - How to find missing libraries when confronted with "[lib].dll: Can't find dependent libraries"

Tags: c, dependencies, java-native-interface

I've been having some trouble moving a C project compiled and running in unix environment (through JNI) to Windows.

While I have been able to compile the program in windows and add the path leading to it in my runtime environment I've been getting the error after `System.loadLibrary()`:

```
classes\x32\coremod.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

How can I discover what libraries I need to have in the `%PATH%` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know this but you can use a program called [DEPENDS.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to discover the dll's which are used by the target.

In my case this highlighted the only dll not already registered, meaning I could simply add it to the `%PATH%` in order to get my program running.